# Laravel firstorcreate OR condition

Tags: laravel

Is it any way to use 'Or' condition in firstorcreate function?

```
Model::firstOrCreate(
   ['name' => $request->get('name'), 'oldname' => $request->get('name')]
);
```

2 condition is related by 'AND', and i want to use 'Or'
But not work with ['newname' => $request->get('name') or 'oldname' => $request->get('name')]

Comment: Have you included the columns to the `filterable` in the `model.php` file?

Comment: when using or: "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'"

Answer (score 0):

The method `firstOrCreate` takes in an optional second argument, you could do something like:

```
Model::firstOrCreate(
   ['name' => $request->get('name')], ['oldname' => $request->get('name')]
);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

From the docs:

```
// Retrieve flight by name, or create it with the name and delayed attributes...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => 'Flight 10'], ['delayed' => 1]
);
```

Comment: i know... But i want is name = 'Flight 10' OR ['delayed' => 1] not name = 'Flight 10' AND ['delayed' => 1]

Comment: @TommyTang You might have to do a little manual programming for this one. If `Model::firstOrCreate(...)->getKey()` is null then attempt the creation with the second array.

Comment: I believe you might have to build your query along with conditionals statements to determine count of models found and create/update accordingly